# shift bits vs multiply in PHP

Tags: php, bit-shift, multiplication

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$start = 1;

$timestart = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $result1 = $start * 4;
}
echo "\n";
echo microtime(1) - $timestart;
echo "\n";

$timestart = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $result2 = $start << 2;
}
echo "\n";
echo microtime(1) - $timestart;
echo "\n";
```

This outputs:

```
0.14027094841003

0.12061500549316
```

I found on the Internet a Google interview question (which I wanted to apply for a developer, but I realize I can't), and one of the questions asked what the fastest way was to multiply a number. My first thought was to use the `*` sign, so I tested it.

My question is, why is shifting bits faster than multiplication?

Comment: Because multiply requires...a multiplication...which requires more time than a bitshift, because it is a more complicated operation?

Comment: @Dan - The question may have more to do with why bitshifting may or may not be equivalent to integer/float multiplication in PHP.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Electronic_usage stating that `To multiply two numbers with n digits using this method, one needs about n2 operations. More formally: using a natural size metric of number of digits, the time complexity of multiplying two n-digit numbers using long multiplication is Θ(n2).`  Bit shifts are a single instruction.

Comment: Incidentally, there are [more ways to perform multiplication than one might expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) -- and different methods excel in different situations.

Comment: @drew010; A [linear-time algorithm is available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Linear_time_multiplication) -- assuming you've got the RAM for some tables.

Comment: why did my comment get removed? i don't understand what was going on and i want to know?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because bit shifting is something the computer does all the time in hardware, it's a no-brainer for the CPU. Multiplying arbitrary numbers is something more difficult, because it can't necessarily be done using simple bit shifting but requires actual work. Multiplying a small integer by 4 happens to be an operation that's identical to a left-shift by 2. But even if the compiler/runtime/CPU optimizes this operation down to a bit shift, some code first needs to *recognize* that it can be optimized this way, which is more work than a simple bit shift itself.

Either way, it's simply more work because the two operations do entirely different things, even if the outcome of certain operations is the same.

Answer (score 13):

Because a bit shift is an operation that can be implemented directly in hardware, whereas hardware rarely has multiplication operations implemented directly.  Multiplication by a power of two can be achieved with a few simple logic gates, whereas multiplication by arbitrary multiplicands requires at the very least several multiplications by powers of two plus an add-to-self operation stacked on top of each other (5 = 2 * 2 + 1).  I don't know if the PHP language specifically implements a shift operation by using whatever low-level calls are available, but I would be surprised if it doesn't.

Source: years of experience + computer science education

Comment: You might want to make it clear that you're talking about hardware efficiency versus ISA.  Both x86 and ARM support multiplication instructions in hardware.  That hardly counts as "rarely".  I think you need to define what you mean by "directly".

Comment: I did not know that x86 and ARM support multiplication instructions in hardware.  By "directly in hardware" I meant logic gates constructed in hardware, without any assembly code to assist.  For example, addition and incrementation can be implemented using only hardware.  I was taught that pure hardware multiplication could require thousands more gates than addition and is rarely implemented in anything but a supercomputer.  Assembly routines can emulate hardware multiplication via repeated addition or other optimizations such as repeated bitshifts and addition-to-self.

Comment: @taz: When you have a billion transistors in a chip, a few thousand for a multiplier isn't much, and the performance gain over shift-and-add is enough to justify it.  Hard to find 32 or 64 bits CPUs that don't have multiply and divide built in.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks for the info. I suspect my instructor may have been a little behind the times.

Answer (score 1):

On Intel sandybrigde CPUs it seems a shift with immediate costs about 1 clock cycle while a multiplication takes about 3-4 cycles. Apparently the whole program performance is affected by more factors than just the raw multiplication but it is enough of making a difference. Most compilers these days optimize multiplication by constants 2^n to shifts (compiler writers love to optimize your code :)) but maybe the PHP interpreter doesn't.

Comment: This was a good answer. Now I'm curious if the PHP interpreter optimizes 2^n multiplies to shifts!